# Cannot export or set variable in new shell

Tags: bash, shell, export

I experienced something weird when working on a issue.
This command does not seem to work. (Using ` to fill blank line).

**When using export**

```
> /bin/bash -c "echo $FOO; export FOO=BAR; echo $FOO"
`
`
```

This command however works as expected.

```
> echo $FOO; FOO=BAR; export FOO=BAR; echo $FOO
`
BAR
```

**Same issue when setting with =**

```
> /bin/bash -c "echo $FOO; FOO=BAR; echo $FOO"
`
`
```

This command however wokrs as expected.

```
> echo $FOO; FOO=BAR; FOO=BAR; echo $FOO
`
BAR
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with the double quotes. Your shell (the 'external' one) will expand `$FOO` before runnig the command. If you set `$FOO` to something (let's say "FOO") you actually run this command.

```
/bin/bash -c "echo FOO; export FOO=BAR; echo FOO"
```

And if you don't set FOO, you run this commmand

```
/bin/bash -c "echo ; export FOO=BAR; echo "
```

Please use single quotes to get what you expect.

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo $FOO; FOO=BAR; echo $FOO'
```